# Books about pic18f?

Tags: microcontroller, pic

Could someone suggest books on PIC18F for me, I used [Gaonkar](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1401879144) for my classes, and I found [Muhammad](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0131194046) and [Huang](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1401839673) to be great references.

Comment: They do books?  I just use the data sheets and app notes.

Comment: And so do the authors of the books, so at best they don't screw it up.

Comment: Book recommendation requests are not suitable questions for this site, as discussed [here on our Meta](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/q/891). They're subjective and have many potentially correct answers. They are, however, a great topic to discuss in [chat]!

Answer (score 4):

The absolute best reference is *PIC18F2525/2620/4525/4620 Data Sheet*, or any of the similar documents for other 18F chips.  The [*PICmicro Mid-Range MCU Family Reference Manual*](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/33023a.pdf) can also be a useful supplement.  The datasheet and the family reference manual are the original source of all information relating to a PIC 18, so at best anything else doesn't garble it or omit things.

Microchip datasheets are well written and easy to follow, but still contain all the necessary information.  If there are specific things you don't understand in them, you can ask here for clarification.

For more discussion on this topic, see my answer to [Good book for PIC 18F beginner?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/31641/4512).

Answer (score 3):

["Microcontroller Theory and Applications with the PIC18F"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470947691), by M. Rafiquzzaman, just came out earlier this year, and covers both assembly and C programming.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some great books on PIC18F microcontrollers:

[Microprocessors: From Assembly Language to C Using the PICI8FXX2: From Assembly Language to C Using the PIC18Fxx2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1584503785)

[The Essential PIC18 Microcontroller](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1849962286)

But I strongly advise to **thoroughly read** the datasheets of the PICs you want to work with.

Answer (score 1):

[Embedded C Programming and the Microchip PIC](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1401837484) by Barnett, Cox and O'Cull.  Good textbook, even though it came out in 2003.  Comes with demo version of CCS compiler, which is used in examples.